# import https is undefined when using Jest with ts-jest (TypeScript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Issue: importing Nodejs native module `https` is `undefined`

dummy.spec.file (my testing file)

```
import https from "https";

it("always true", () => {
  console.log("https:");
  console.log(https); // <- this is undefined
  expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

jest.config.js (Jest config file)

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

Nodejs version: v16.13.0
Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.6.2",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3"
  }
```

How can I make `https` work properly inside a testing file (jest + typescript) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason could be your Typescript configuration. Check that if it's causing any issues with the https module import.
In your tsconfig.json file, make sure you have "module": "CommonJS" and "esModuleInterop": true

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though `tsc --init` creates the deafult `tsconfig.json` with `"esModuleInterop": true,`, which we may thought that it's the default value for field `esModuleInterop` is `true` when no `tsconfig.son` is present, we need to explicitly put that line in order import native modules as `https` properly